# Having trouble moving my skspritenodes EDIT:

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

```
func increaseSnakeLength(){

    snakeArray.append(snakeLength)
    inc += snakeBody.size.height

    if snakeMovingLeft == true{
        snakeLength = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
        snakeLength.position = CGPointMake(snakeBody.position.x + inc, snakeBody.position.y )
        addChild(snakeLength)
    }
    if snakeMovingRight == true{
        snakeLength = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
        snakeLength.position = CGPointMake(snakeBody.position.x - inc, snakeBody.position.y)
        addChild(snakeLength)
    }
    if snakeMovingUp == true{
        snakeLength = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
        snakeLength.position = CGPointMake(snakeBody.position.x, snakeBody.position.y - inc)
        addChild(snakeLength)
    }
    if snakeMovingDown == true{
        snakeLength = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
        snakeLength.position = CGPointMake(snakeBody.position.x, snakeBody.position.y + inc)
        addChild(snakeLength)
    }
}
func moveSnake(){

    if snakeArray.count > 0{
        snakeLength.position = CGPointMake(snakeBody.position.x, snakeBody.position.y)
    }
    snakeBody.position = CGPointMake(snakeHead.position.x, snakeHead.position.y)
    snakeHead.position = CGPointMake(snakeHead.position.x + snakeX, snakeHead.position.y + snakeY)
}
```

[Snake Game][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhxSO.png

My function increaseSnakeLength() adds a new snakeLength block to the scene when the snakeHead makes contact with my food. Then in my moveSnake() function i move the snake blocks but when i move the snakeLength block it only moves the newest block and leaves the old block not moving. You can see this in the image above. I am not sure how to move all the snakeLength blocks at the same time.

Comment: Does the snake only move up/down/left/right or can it move at any angle?

Comment: The snake only moves left/right/up/down according to the direction of swipe

Answer (score 0):

It appears `snakeLength` is a global variable. This means each time you eat the food, you are overwriting your reference to it.  In your `moveSnake()`, you check the size of the `snakeArray`, but then never access the array itself.  I recommend a `for` loop going through all of the indexes, updating their positions.

I also recommend putting `snakeArray.append(snakeLength)` at the bottom of the `increaseSnakeLength()` to have it get the newest snake part added to it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a perfect example for using a `SKNode` as a parent node. `SKNode`s serve as a abstract container for your sprites which allows you to move/scale/animate grouped sprites/nodes collectively.

Instead of adding your sprites to the scene itself, try something like this:

Create a `SKNode` class for your snake (that lets you control the snake and separate concerns a little better):

```
class Snake : SKNode {

    func grow(){
        let snakeLength = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
        // NOTE! position will now be relative to this node
        // take this into account for your positioning
        snakeLength.position = CGPointMake(snakeBody.position.x - inc,         snakeBody.position.y)
        self.addChild(snakeLength)
    }  

    func moveLeft() { // moves the snake parts to the left (do this for all your directions)
        // iterate over all your snake parts and move them accordingly
        for snakePart in self.children {

        }
    }      

}
```

In your main scene you can then create the snake:

```
let snake = Snake()

// when the snake eats food, grow the snake
snake.grow()
```

Also move the snake and it's parts by executing actions on the snake itself:

```
// In your main scene
snake.moveLeft()
```